# Why Handler leak issue won't happen in thread other than the main thread

Tags: android

I have code in activity as below

```
Handler handler = new Handler(){
        @Override
        public void dispatchMessage(Message msg) {
            super.dispatchMessage(msg);
        }
    };
```

Android Studio lint:

> **Handler reference leaks**
>
> Since this Handler is declared as an inner class, it may prevent the outer class from being garbage collected. **If the Handler is using a Looper or MessageQueue for a thread other than the main thread, then there is no issue.** If the Handler is using the Looper or MessageQueue of the main thread, you need to fix your Handler declaration, as follows: Declare the Handler as a static class; In the outer class, instantiate a WeakReference to the outer class and pass this object to your Handler when you instantiate the Handler; Make all references to members of the outer class using the WeakReference object.

I know Handler reference leaks because it holds strong reference of activity, and the activity can not be collected by garbage collection, but why Handler leak issue won't happen in thread other than the main thread? The main thread lifecycle is as long as application matters?

Comment: Did you figure this out? Because no 3 years later I have the same question.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the the [Handler](http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/Handler.java) implementation then you will see that initially it does not pass its own reference to any outside (ie. Looper) objects. It does pass its reference outside once you [post](http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/Handler.java#enqueueMessage) a message, a `this` reference is assigned to message `target` field. Now if your message is long lived (it was posted with longer delay), then it might outlive your Activity life causing resources leaks. The actual reason is the main thread message queue which holds a message with reference to your handler which also contains a reference to your activity. This reference leak happens when your Handler is inner static in your activity.

So lets now replace main thread message queue with some other thread message queue. Because this is what this Warning message is talking about. Assume that your Handler is still inner static to your activity, but it uses a looper of some other thread, lets say you want to post messages to this thread with some delay. Once your delayed message gets into message queue of this worker thread, it will still cause a reference leak - it will be keeping for some indefinite time a reference to your handler which will also keep reference to your activity.

So my understanding is that in the above scenario this Warning is not quite right. Or maybe I am missing something.

You could argue that this thread could be terminated once Activity.onDestroy gets called, this of course would prevent reference leaks here.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio lint says about Handler *inside* Looper or MessageQueue.
An example from [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html):

```java
class LooperThread extends Thread {
  public Handler mHandler;

  public void run() {
      Looper.prepare();

      mHandler = new Handler() {
          public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
              // process incoming messages here
          }
      };

      Looper.loop();
  }
}
```

This obviously does not hold a reference to any Activity, thus is not leaking.